# Create pandas dataframe where each cell basis on slope calculation with time series rows from another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, regression

I have a dataframe with about 40 columns and about 100000 rows:

```
ID MONTH_NUM_
   FROM_EVENT F1    F2       F3     F4  etc…
2   1         4.0   133.0   28.0    NaN 
2   2         NaN   132.0   29.0    24.0    
2   3         NaN   131.0   NaN     29.0    
2   4         4.0   130.0   31.0    7.0 
2   5        8.0    129.0   26.0    2.0 
2   6        8.0    128.0   25.0    3.0 
4   1        5.0    139.0   29.0    7.0 
4   2        5.0    138.0   NaN     22.0    
4   3        5.0    137.0   30.0    28.0    
4   4        5.0    136.0   29.0    25.0    
4   5        5.0    135.0   NaN     27.0    
4   6        5.0    134.0   27.0    29.0
```

etc…

each columns F is a 6m time series data with NaN for each rows ID client

I want to output new dataframe without monthes like so:

```
    ID  F1  F2  F3  F4  etc…
2  
4
```

etc…

where each cell of new data frame is a slope calculation of 6m time series for each F colums with following code example:

```
x = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] #its constanta for each calcul, monthes with reverse orders because 1 is last month before event prediction
y = df.F1[df['ID']==2]

xm = np.ma.masked_array(x,mask=np.isnan(y)).compressed() #ignore Nans
ym = np.ma.masked_array(y,mask=np.isnan(y)).compressed() #ignore Nans
from scipy.stats import linregress
linregress(xm, ym).slope
```

What is the  efficient way to looping  this calculation and create new df? 
Thanx in advance...